# Aligning Buefy dropdown menu to avoid chopping off side

Tags: bulma, buefy

I have a Buefy dropdown triggered from an icon positioned at the 
right side of my page.
When I activate it, the left side of the menu produced is aligned 
with the icon and the right side of the menu, being wider than the 
icon, extends off the page to the right and is chopped off as can
be seen here:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
      <section class="section">
        <div class="columns">
          <div class="column">Some info with dropdown menu at right ---&gt;</div>
          <div class="column is-narrow">
            <b-dropdown hoverable is-bottom-left>
              <i class="is-info" slot="trigger">@</i>
              <b-dropdown-item>Action</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item>Another action</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item>Something else</b-dropdown-item>
              </b-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div><!--#id="app"-->
  <script>
    const app = new Vue()
    app.$mount('#app')
    </script>
```

(To see the effect you will probably have to click
the Full Page link to get the Results window
wide enough so that the "@" doesnt wrap to the left side.)

Bulma has the ability to right-align the menu so that the left side 
of the menu extends into the page making it fully visible.

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/#right-aligned

How do I get the same effect in Buefy?  I find the Buefy by-example docs
excessively terse but I thought I could add "is-bottom-left" to the 
`<b-dropdown>` element.  As the snippet shows though, that has no effect.

Further, when the page in narrowed, the dropdown icon will be repositioned 
to the left side of the page.  Assuming there is a fix for the above problem, 
how to return the menu alignment back to what it was (left side aligned) in 
this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
<b-dropdown class="is-right">
    ...                             
</b-dropdown>
```

just use the class 'is-right' on the b-dropdown element